# Why phpMailer works only on local server?

Tags: php, smtp, localhost, phpmailer

I've a PHP file which uses phpMailer to send emails through SMTP. It works well while I use it on localhost (With Xampp). But when I put the same file on a remote server, it returns errors and any email won't be sent.

```
2018-03-05 20:12:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-03-05 20:12:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO sample-domain.com
2018-03-05 20:12:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-03-05 20:12:44 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 
2018-03-05 20:12:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO sample-domain.com
2018-03-05 20:12:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-03-05 20:12:44 SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed: 
2018-03-05 20:12:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-03-05 20:12:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-03-05 20:12:44 SMTP ERROR: STARTTLS command failed: 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2018-03-05 20:12:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-03-05 20:12:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-03-05 20:12:44 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

What is this difference for? How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you checked credentials are correct? Is `sample-domain.com` what is showing or is that you redacting?

Comment: The port it uses may be blocked on your remote server.

Comment: never got to check credentials @LawrenceCherone that comes after connection. check your host is not blocking the port a lot of hosts do this

Comment: Sorry I ment is sample-domain.com or 25 correct as well not just user pass.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `simple-domain.com` is just a sample here. I had the real information in my code. Credentials are correct because I am able to send emails with them through localhost

Comment: @Don'tPanic I used the same port number while sending emails from localhost

Comment: Have you checked SMTP greeting message of the remote SMTP host?  (`telnet HOSTNAME 25`)  Maybe you client is rejected in  SMTP greeting message.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing to do with credentials - it's not getting as far as trying them. Read the troubleshooting guide - you have a TLS problem, most likely that your CA certificates are out of date.